# How to generate a random number for a model field using Factory Boy

Tags: python, django, factory-boy

I need to create some fake data using [`factory boy`](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). I have the following model:

```
class Fabric(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10, null=True, blank=False)
```

I need to create a factory based on this model, and I would like the price to have a random value between 1 and 100.

```
class FabricFactory(DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = Fabric

    title = factory.Faker('name')
    description = factory.Faker('catch_phrase')
    price = random.randrange(MIN_PRICE, MAX_PRICE + 1)
```

The problem with this is that I am always getting the same price for every instance.

Comment: if I am understanding correctly (I don't have any experience with `factory_boy`) it is a fixture, that gets reused, it seems it's only being instantiated once and the scope of this fixture is your whole session. is there any way to modify the scope of your fixture within `factory_boy`?

Comment: Try a [fuzzy attribute](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fuzzy.html).

Comment: @KlausD., I thought of this option, but it seems using a lazy attribute is simpler.

Comment: @aws_appretice, thanks for your hint. It is definitely what using a lazy attribute does.

Comment: glad you figured it out :thumbsup:

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was able to figure out this problem by using a [lazy attribute](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#lazy-attributes) (`factory.LazyAttribute`). From the docs:

> Most factory attributes can be added using static values that are evaluated when the factory is defined, but some attributes (such as fields whose value is computed from other elements) will need values assigned each time an instance is generated.

```
class FabricFactory(DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = Fabric

    title = factory.Faker('name')
    description = factory.Faker('catch_phrase')
    price = factory.LazyAttribute(random.randrange(MIN_PRICE, MAX_PRICE + 1))
```

Comment: In my case I needed to use lambda function

```number_field = factory.LazyAttribute(lambda x: random.randrange(0, 10000))```

Comment: Yeah this example will generate a single random number at import-time ...

Comment: this returns `TypeError: 'int' object is not callable`

Answer (score 11):

You can use python providers as well.

```
class MyModel(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory)
  number_field = factory.Faker('pyint', min_value=0, max_value=1000)
  class Meta:
    model = SomeModel
```

[Documentation](https://faker.readthedocs.io/en/master/providers/faker.providers.python.html)

Comment: Did adding `min_value` or `max_value` worked for you? I'm trying to do the same with `pydecimal` but adding `left_digits` and `right_digits` still crashes my tests with numeric field overflow

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Yes what I posted worked correctly for me. Try adjusting your left and right digits to a smaller number, also debugging to see which number is generating and why is giving you that error.

Comment: I always forget faker has a python provider! There's also a pydecimal and a pyfloat provider (which is what I needed)

Answer (score 4):

In my case, `LazyAttribute` didn't worked.

I found the best way to generate a 10 digit random number using factory boy was something like this:

```
import factory.fuzzy

class CustomUserFactory(DjangoModelFactory):
        phone_number = factory.fuzzy.FuzzyInteger(9000000000, 9999999999)
```

The parameters provided inside `FuzzyInteger()` are the lower limit and the upper limit between which the random numbers will be generated.

Comment: [Fuzzy is deprecated in favour of faker](https://github.com/FactoryBoy/factory_boy/issues/271/), so although it works, I would not recommend this approach

Answer (score 2):

You can use FuzzyDecimal.

```
import factory.fuzzy 


class ExampleModel(DjangoModelFactory):
    price = factory.fuzzy.FuzzyDecimal(low=min_price, high=max_price, precision=numbers_of_decimals_you_need)
```

already used.

Comment: [Fuzzy is deprecated in favour of faker](https://github.com/FactoryBoy/factory_boy/issues/271/), so although it works, I would not recommend this approach